# Angular not sending request to API

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

My Angular 8 service is executed but the API Method is not.

Angular Service:

```
createFile(mapping: UniqueCustomerTestMatched[] {
    const endpoint = 'https://localhost:44398/api/mapping/createFiles';
    this.loading = true;
    var data = JSON.stringify(mapping);
    console.log("Sending mapping to API: " + data);
    return this.httpClient.post(endpoint, { fileContent: data});
}
```

ASP.NET API:

```
[HttpPost("createFiles")]
    public ActionResult<List<CustomerTestMatched>> CreateFiles([FromBody]UploadInfo rawData)
    {
```

What could it be? I've implemented other post methods the exact same way that work.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing a `subscribe` method at the end.

Should be:

`this.httpClient.post(endpoint, { fileContent: data}).subscribe()`